# How to access 2D Array of Objects Variables?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, parsing, multidimensional-array

I am working on Json parsing project in C#, the classes listed below are generated by the PastSpecial feature in VS.

I need to access like the variables inside these classes, for example a way to access the 'id' string var or the "Pou" class?

Is there any like 'straighforward' to implement this in C#?

Thanks in Advance,
Daniel

Main class: 'House'

```
    public class TEST
{
    public Hn[][] hn{ get; set; }
    public An[][] an{ get; set; }
}
public class Pou
{
    public int de{ get; set; }
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public int cn{ get; set; }
}

public class Hn
{
    public DateTime date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? date2 { get; set; }
    public Pou[] pou{ get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `obj.hn[0][0].id`?

Comment: Hope my boss will not see this kind of question i did asked.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's by obj.hn[0][0].id
Impressive huh?